# Space between text area and footer area

Tags: header-footer, margins

How to control the vertical space between the text area and the footer area?

If I change the value of `\textheight` the footer comes together.

If I change the value of `bottom` using `geometry` package, the footer is always exactly below the last line of the text. Even if I use the `includefoot` option.

I know that the space between the header and the text area is controllable.

Why is not possible to do the same with the footer?

For example, how to always keep (without overfull) a vertical space of 4cm between the last line and the footer?

Comment: I'd just discovered that the `geometry` package allows `footskip` option.

Comment: Should we close this question?

Comment: @karlkoeller, I think so. May I delete it?

Comment: You could answer the question, too ... unless that's frowned upon for some reaon.

Comment: Perfectly legitimate to answer one's own question; you should do just that.

Answer (score 13):

I found the answer by myself. We can change the value of `\footskip` which represents the vertical space between the bottom of footer box and the bottom of the text area.

I draw the figure below to exemplify this. Also you can play a little with the [GeoGebra construction here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/jyvutqaa) showing those variables.

[image]

Comment: @ThomasWeller, thanks. I edited the link. Please, try it now.